# Avoiding duplicate values while editing:

Tags: php, laravel

When a user tries to edit their region, I've showed their previous region with selected but their previous region is also on dropdown box. How can we show that region has only one?

In code below, `$user->region->region_name` and one of the `$reg->region_name` are same.

```
 <select  name="region" id="region" class="form-control" required>
         <option value="{{ $user->region_id}}" selected>{{$user->region->region_name}}</option>
           @foreach($region as $reg)
             <option value="{{$reg->id}}">{{$reg->region_name}}</option>
           @endforeach                
  </select><br>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use simple conditional to skip selected region:

```
@foreach ($region as $reg)
    @if ($user->region_id !== $reg->id)
        <option value="{{ $reg->id }}">{{ $reg->region_name }}</option>
    @endif
@endforeach
```